# Unclear of posting data with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm learning to program and I have come along this tutorial:

http://www.w3resource.com/ajax/working-with-PHP-and-MySQL.php

there is one thing that is unclear to me. In this example there is a assignment:

```
var data = "book_name=" + book;
```

data is sent to php file and it is retrieved with statment

```
 $book_name = $_POST['book_name'];
```

Does `=` sign in assignment means some kind of reference here? So in php we retrieve `book_name` which in turns refers to book string object?

Am i getting this or am i shooting at fence?

Thans for any answer

Comment: It's just irrelevant it used the same name for the assigned var, it could just be `$myvar = $_POST['book_name']`.. is that what you are asking?

Comment: It sounds like you got it right, when values are sent over post/get, it is passed as a key=value in a string. php converts this to an array that you can index based on the key from the string.

Answer (score 1):

The = sign in the assignment here is just a way of linking the attribute to the value...so let's say book was "Robinson Crusoe"

you'd pass "book_name=Robinson Crusoe" via POST , and when you retrieve it with $book_name = $POST['book_name'];  , book name becomes "Robinson Crusoe".  Does this help at all?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as you retrieve POST fields. In the "send" method you should pass the arguments in a form "arg=value". For instance, if you want to send two fields you should do:

xhr.send("arg1=value1&arg2=value2")

when retrieve like that

$_POST["arg1"] it will return "value1"
$_POST["arg2"] it will return "value2"

For further information read this [article](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)!

Answer (score 0):

the `=` sign  is a [assignment operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php)

it gives to the operand on the left the value of the operand on the right. nothing more, nothing less.

In your example, you `data` variable is probably passed to a post request, resolving in it containing the book, but as [mentionned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19821217/unclear-of-posting-data-with-ajax/19821632#comment29471364_19821217) on your question, they could be named differently and it would make no difference.